# Getting "The process cannot access the file" error in Visual Studio, preventing running or rebuilding

Tags: visual-studio, build

I have tried what many things suggested on other answers to this kind of problem.

I have this problem with all my projects.

Errors related to deleting or accessing the EXE files in the project's path.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS2012  Cannot open 'c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\blahtest1\blahtest1\obj\Debug\blahtest1.exe' for writing -- 'Access to the path 'c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\blahtest1\blahtest1\obj\Debug\blahtest1.exe' is denied.'  blahtest1   c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\blahtest1\blahtest1\CSC 1   Active
```

I wrote a bat file for whatever project i'm working on to help with the situation.. It just shows whether those files are there and it tries to delete them.

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\blahtest1\blahtest1
>type refreshprog.bat
dir /b ".\bin\Debug\*.exe"

dir /b ".\obj\Debug\*.exe"

del ".\bin\Debug\*.exe"

del ".\obj\Debug\*.exe"
C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\blahtest1\blahtest1
>
```

Sometimes I try to unlock those files with a program like IObit unlocker, or unlocker.  Then delete them.

I've tried process explorer to see what is locking it but no luck.

After a while it can suddenly become possible to remove them.

Even if it succeeds I can still then get the error mentioned above.

Other errors I get where I then try my bat file and try manually trying to delete the files

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\blahtest1.exe" to "bin\Debug\blahtest1.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\blahtest1.exe' because it is being used by another process.   blahtest1           
Error       Could not copy "obj\Debug\blahtest1.exe" to "bin\Debug\blahtest1.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.  blahtest1
```

I don't know what it was that caused this to happen either

Cleaning the project often won't help. I can get an error like this

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Unable to delete file "c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\blahtest1\blahtest1\bin\Debug\chromedriver.exe". Access to the path 'c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\blahtest1\blahtest1\bin\Debug\chromedriver.exe' is denied.  blahtest1
```

It can be a barebones program, it could be a console application with nothing in the main method.  It could be a winforms program.

I can right click the profile, see it's on read only, untick it, try to apply to all subfolders, then get an access denied message

[image]

If I look at old projects created before the problem occurred, I see they also show as read-only. So I don't know if folders are meant to be read-only.. But regardless, I can't take them off read-only.

I then tried it again, and it said it couldn't find that EXE file. (Maybe I managed to delete it or VS did, I don't know). But then I tried making the folder not read-only again, and it claims that it went not read-only. Then I go to properties of the folder again and it shows as read-only again!

The read-only part doesn't seem to be a problem, because there are times when VS manages to rebuild or clean a project, and it still manages it when the project folder is set to read-only

I just tried it a few times now and have seen that when it doesn't work, I can see with process explorer it's locked by system pid-4, so that doesn't help me much as it doesn't tell me what is locking it.  I then try end tasking explorer. Then it worked. Then I checked with process explorer again and it shows it's locked by pid-4, but this time visual studio is able to write.

I don't really know how to go about dealing with this! I've had the problem for months.  My HDD is a bit low right now like 500MB left.. But I think I probably had this problem when there was a few GB left. And other programs are running ok.

[image]

Comment: It's possible that your anti-virus, anti-malware, or Windows Defender is locking the files to scan them.  Try excluding your projects directory from any scanner that you have running.

Comment: @jonsca  ok I just quit malware bytes and zamana. I see Microsoft security essentials and windows defender are off.   I just tried taking a folder off read only, it says ok. Then I looked again and it's read-only again.  So I guess that still doesn't look right? I'll try running a program and see if I still see the problem described in my question

Comment: @jonsca hmm it might work now.. though I can't know for sure 'cos the problem is on and off.. I should try closing visual studio and seeing if process explorer still shows the folder as in use.. and if there is a difference depending on whether those programs are running.  It will take some time to verify if that was indeed the problem..

Comment: I just read https://forums.malwarebytes.com/topic/202997-mbam-keeps-locking-visual-studio-compiled-executable-preventing-subsequent-rebuild-and-debug/  so that looks very much like the culprit   I haven't had an issue since solving it and normally I would have. So I think this solved it.  And starting MBAM agani hasn't caused the issue but that makes sense 'cos that link says it happens when MBAM has been running for a while like 5 days+.

Comment: (still a mystery re the read-only but I think that's not important 'cos that doesn't seem to stop VS from doing a build)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that one of your security applications (e.g., Malwarebytes or even Windows Defender) is locking the .exe files to scan them for malicious activity.

The way to avoid this is to whitelist your project directories with the application, and in particular your `bin\debug`, etc.

As you have confirmed in the comments this is a [known issue](https://forums.malwarebytes.com/topic/202997-mbam-keeps-locking-visual-studio-compiled-executable-preventing-subsequent-rebuild-and-debug/) with Malwarebytes.  In the linked article, it says that you need to whitelist `vshost.exe` as well, but I don't know that it's absolutely necessary.